# How connect existing sqlite database with C# application

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

this create a new database "MyDatabase.sqlite" for each time but I want to connect my existing data base with c#
Any One Please help for the same

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
    m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
    m_dbConnection.Open();

    //my query here

     m_dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: It seems that you forgot to paste the code

Comment: Code? did you forget to put the code?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
            m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
            m_dbConnection.Open();

            //my query here

            m_dbConnection.Close();

        }

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you want to connect to a different database instead of "MyDatabase.sqlite". You just need to change the "Data Source" to point to your database.

```
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=c:\myexistingdb.db;Version=3;");
```

You may want to check out connection strings, if you need username, passwords, etc.